# Select value from drop down list and second drop down list auto changed

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have one table in my database called as company and inside company table there are 3 columns name Id,Company_Name and location.
I have two drop down list. First drop down list displaying only Company name and according to company name location will change in second drop down list.
I did some code but in second drop down i am getting all location name.

```html
<?php


//$comp=$_POST['Company'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "demo_db";


    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from company";// it displaying all company name in my first drop down list
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));


if (isset($_POST['Company'])) {

    $name=$_POST['Company'];
    $sql = "select * from company where Company_name=$name";

}
    $result_loc = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));


    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 

    <select onchange='this.form.submit();' name="Company">
            <option value="Select your Location1" disabled selected>Select your company</option>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row[1];?>"><?php echo $row[1];?></option>
            <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>

 <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select your location</option>
             <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_loc)):;?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row[2];?>"><?php echo $row[2];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
 </select>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check at this site : http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php

Comment: Firstly - the SELECT menus are not within a form so the `onchange` event handler would not be correct, Secondly use an Ajax function to send a request ( POST ) that will be used to query the database to get the contents for the second ( dependant ) SELECT menu.

Comment: On change of first select box you have to do ajax call and find the location in the ajax file and from the response bind the location to the second dropdown.

Comment: Yes, I checked that before but still getting issue

Comment: Can we do without Ajax?

Comment: Yes you can do it without AJAX. Just rebuild the page.

Comment: Mr.Erwin Moller, Can you help me with code..Please

Answer (score 0):

To aid you in chaining SELECT menus using ajax the following might prove useful - you should be able to modify this to suit your db structure and naming conventions. You can run this "as-is" to see the results - hope it will prove useful.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'], $_POST['id'] ) ){

        $action=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $id=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

        if( $action && $id && !is_nan( $id ) ){
            $sql='select * from table where id=?';
            /* etc ~ generic sql example only ! */

            /* query db*/

            /* process recordset and build menu data */



            /* 
                demo response sent back to aajx callback
                In reality this would be dynamically generated with
                results from the db query above.
            */
            for( $i=0; $i < 10; $i++ )echo "<option value='Location-$id-$i'>Location-$id-$i";
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dependent / Chained SELECT menus</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
            /* Basic Ajax function */
            function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
                /*
                    m=Method,
                    u=Url,
                    p=Params,
                    c=Callback,
                    o=Options
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }


            /* Callback function to populate second menu */
            function createmenu(r,o,h){
                /*
                    r=response
                    o=options ( sent by ajax function )
                    h=response headers
                */
                o.menu.innerHTML=r;
            }



            function bindEvents(){
                /* Get references to the two dropdown menus */
                var oSelCompany=document.querySelectorAll('select[name="Company"]')[0];
                var oSelLocation=document.querySelectorAll('select[name="Locations"]')[0];

                /* Assign an `onchange` event listener */
                oSelCompany.onchange=function(e){

                    var method='post';
                    var url=location.href;

                    /* the parameters to send to the PHP script */
                    var params={
                        'action':'getmenu',
                        'id':this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ].value
                    };

                    /* Options to pass to the ajax callback */
                    var opts={
                        menu:oSelLocation
                    };

                    /* make the ajax request */
                    ajax.call( this, method, url, params, createmenu, opts );

                }.bind( oSelCompany );
            }

            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents,false );
        </script>
        <style type='text/css' charset='utf-8'>
            select {padding:1rem;width:300px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <select name='Company'>
                <option value=1>One
                <option value=2>Two
                <option value=3>Three
                <option value=4>Four
                <option value=5>Five
            </select>
            <select name='Locations'></select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mr.RamRaider.I appreciate your efforts but can you help me in a simple way because I am new in programming and your code is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Demo for you. suppose you have company name and company has multiple location Example (id,name,location) :1,TCS,Banglore  2,TCS,Hyderabad

```
<?php 
 /*database connection*/ 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","search");
?> 
<script>
function test(name)
 {
  // new file name f1.php
var strURL = "f1.php?name="+name;
    var ax=new XMLHttpRequest();
       ax.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
        if(ax.readyState==4){
         document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = ax.responseText;

     }
     }
         ax.open("GET",strURL, true);
         ax.send(null); 
      }
</script>
 <?php 
  $sql= mysqli_query($con,"select * from company GROUP BY name  ");
     //print_r($sql);
     ?>
        <select>
               <option value="0">select company name</option>
    <?php   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
           ?>
    <option onclick="test('<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>');" id="<?php echo $i++."der" ;?>"> <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>


       <?php  }
?>
 </select> 
 <div id="myid"></div>
```

Now Create a new file f1.php where you can run another mysql query to send the name of company you have selected by test function.here is the code

```
   <?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","search");
  if(isset($_GET['name']))
 {

   $name = $_GET['name'];
   }
   $sql= mysqli_query($con,"select * from company where name='$name'");
    ?>
   <select  name="city">
      <option>Select location</option>
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))  
    { ?>
   <option value=<?php echo $row['location']?>><?php echo $row['location']?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: Sorry, Mr.Swapnil jain I tried but nothing is happening.

Comment: what is problem are you facing?

Comment: this is the database i made
INSERT INTO `company` (`id`, `name`, `location`) VALUES
(1, 'TWS', 'indore'),
(2, 'TWS', 'bhopal'),
(3, 'Infosys', 'hyderabad'),
(4, 'Infosys', 'banglore'),
(5, 'TCS', 'pune'),
(6, 'TCS', 'Mumbai');

Comment: You are sharing your code.Is it possible to make changes in my code?

Comment: i am not sharing my code. Actually i have modified your code in much simpler way so that it will be easy for you to understand that how flow is going.

Comment: I tried your code but I am getting only one drop down and that is only Company name. I select company name but not action taking.Can you share demo..Please

Comment: i have created a table name company which has three columns id,name,location and inserted a value see in second comment. now just put first part of the code in your file and then create a new file named f1.php and put second part of the code with database connection. your location of company will come from second file by ajax

Comment: Yes, Mr.Swapnil I got it your description and I haven't changed any things except database connection but i don't know why it's not working

Comment: try in Mozilla Firefox may be JavaScript will not be accepted in chrome

Comment: may be your browser JavaScript issue you can resolve it manually or you can also use jquery library for ajax function. if you understand the flow. if solution works  for you  mark it right.